# What is the most practical board representation for a magic bitboard move generation system?

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, chess

I am rewriting a chess engine I wrote to run on magic bitboards. I have the magic functions written and they take a square of the piece and an occupancy bitboard as parameters. What I am having debates with myself is which one of these board representation schemes is faster/more practical:

scheme 1: There is a bitboard for each type of piece, 1 for white knights, 1 for black rooks. . . , and in order to generate moves and push them to the move stack, I must serialize them to find the square of the piece and then call the magic function. Then I must serialize that move bitboard and push them. The advantage is is that the attacking and occupancy bitboards are closer at hand.

scheme 2: A simple piece centric array [2][16] or [32] contains the square indices of the pieces. A simply loopthrough and call of the functions is all it takes for the move bitboards. I then serialize those bitboards and push them to the move stack. I also have to maintain an occupancy bitboard. I guess getting an attack bitboard shouldn't be any different: I have to once again generate all the move bitboards and, instead of serializing them, I bitwise operate them in a mashup of magic.

I'm leaning towards scheme 2, but for some reason I think there is some sort of implementation similar to scheme 1 that is standard. For some reason I can't find drawbacks of making a "bitboard" engine without actually using bitboards. I wouldn't even be using bitboards for king and knight data, just a quick array lookup.

I guess my question is more of whether there is a better way to do this board representation, because I remember reading that keeping a bitboard for each type of piece is standard (maybe this is only necessary with rotated bitboards?). I'm relatively new to bitboard engines but I've read a lot and I've implemented the magic method. I certainly like the piece centric array approach - it makes a lot of arbitrary stuff like printing the board to the screen easier, but if there is a better/equal/more standard way can someone please point it out? Thanks in advance - I know this is a fairly specific question and difficult to answer unless you are very familiar with chess programming.

Last minute question: how is the speed of a lookup into a 2D array measure up to using a 1D array and adding 16 * team_side to the normal index to lookup the piece?

**edit**: I thought I should add that I am valuing speed over almost all else in my chess implementation. Why else would I go with magic bitboards as opposed to simply arrays with slide data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard answer to this, sorry.

The number and types of data structures you need depends on *exactly* what you want to do in your program. For example, having more than one representation of the pieces on the board makes some operations faster. On the other hand, it takes more time to update your data during each move.

To get the maximum speed, it is your job to find out what works best for *your* program. Does maintaining an extra array of pieces result in a net speedup for a program? It depends!

Sometimes it is a net gain to maintain a data structure, sometimes you can delay the calculations and cache the result, and sometimes you just calculate it when needed (and hope it isn't needed very often).